# Why are two completely independent variables still linked through the Pythagorean theorem?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

If I have two axes A (apples) and B (bananas), and I plot the point 
where I have 3 apples and 4 bananas, then I would say I have 7 pieces 
of fruit. However, Pythagoras would say I have 5 pieces of fruit 
sqrt(3^2+4^2). Who is right, me or Pythagoras? :)

I came up with the axes of apples and bananas, because I don't 
understand why two completely independent variables still have 
something to do with each other through the pythagorean theorem.

The question came up as I was thinking about complex numbers. I 
understand that the operation of "multiplying by i" is the same as 
rotating 90 degrees anticlockwise. But I still don't understand what 
happens with my apples if I multiply 3 apples by i. Do my apples 
suddenly become bananas?

Comment: For your first paragraph, you're comparing apples and bananas :-P  You're both 'right', in the sense that you're using different metrics on the same space.  $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}$ is the Euclidean metric, and going 4 units along the apples axis and 3 along the bananas axis and adding them up is often called the 'taxicab' or 'manhattan' metric.

Answer (score 1):

If you take three steps forward, and then four steps to the left $($or to the right, it doesn't matter$)$, you are five steps away from your original position, despite the fact that you've made seven steps to arrive there. And if you take $100$ steps forward, and then $100$ steps backwards, then you are exactly where you started, despite the fact that it took you $200$ steps to arrive there, when you could just as easily have achieved the same result by doing nothing at all ! :-$)$

Comment: Also, if you take a straight road and multiply it by *i*, it becomes a ladder; if you multiply it by $-i$, it becomes a well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have two independent variables which are *not totally independent*. Pythagorean Theorem constrains the values of $A$,$B$,$C$ to be:

1. Positive real values
2. The direction of $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ must be perpendicular.

So yes, you are correct in your answers if you throw out at least condition #2. Pythagorean Theorem doesn't throw it out, so the independent variables aren't fully independent. Also, you can change $A$ or $B$ however you like, because $C$ is a dependent variable which "soaks up" the difference.